# LiteSpeed Cache Plugin Error img-optm.cls.php on line 614

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

So I have a custom WordPress theme with ACF built-in and also uses LiteSpeed Cache plugin on the site but its just constantly throwing me the same error and I can't seem to figure out what to do?

```
Error Reporting on :[2023-07-20 11:06:48]

Error number :ErrorException

Error message :Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Stack trace :
#0 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/img-optm.cls.php(614): errorHandler(8, 'Trying to acces...', '/home/echoridge...', 614, Array)
#1 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/img-optm.cls.php(332): LiteSpeed\Img_Optm->_send_request()
#2 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/img-optm.cls.php(158): LiteSpeed\Img_Optm->new_req()
#3 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): LiteSpeed\Img_Optm::cron_auto_request()
#4 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#5 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#6 /home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-cron.php(188): do_action_ref_array('litespeed_task_...', Array)
#7 {main}

Thrown in :/home/mycustomwebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/img-optm.cls.php on line 614
```

Comment: the relevant line `(empty($_img_info['url']) || empty($_img_info['md5'])` suggest that `$_img_info` is `false` and that the image info can't be retrieved. try to debug to find out why. maybe a php module is missing

Comment: What version of php do you run?

Comment: I am still running PHP 7.4 - do you think maybe that is the issue here?